# Reinstalling Windows without losing data

Tags: windows, reinstall

I'm having a trouble with my audio so I asked my notebook support for help and they said it's possible for me to reinstall Windows; but I don't want to lose my data.

Is it possible for me to reinstall Windows without losing my data? Or I must do a backup?

Comment: did you try reinstalling the audio driver?

Comment: Yes, that's why I called the support

Comment: Your user files should not be in the C partition in the first place. I recommend you move them to a seperate data partition. Long time ago I made a video that shows you how to do that. ==> https://vimeo.com/8722519

Comment: Yes, instead of doing a custom install, select Upgrade, and it will install Windows, replaced the old one, but not delete your data. It functions in a very similar fashion as the repair install use to.

Answer (score 0):

install windows over the current one and installation puts your data into a folder in c: called windows.old

be careful. do you mean installing windows or using one of those recovery dvds? for this method im assuming you have a windows dvd.

if you have a recovery dvd, you need to copy your files and folders to some drive other than c: (physical or logical drive) and tell recovery program to recover c: only.

also, you dont need to reinstall windows just because your audio doesnt work. did you try reinstalling audio driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "repair install" which actually keeps your files and basically just replaces the C:\Windows\ system files with stock versions.  The exact steps depend on which version of Windows you are running.

Otherwise, you need to backup all files and do a clean reinstall, then restore files to the newly refreshed OS.